# Horizontal Legend with g_legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using the commonly referenced g_legend function to pull a legend out of a graph made with ggplot2 such that I can organize it with multiple plots using grid.arrange.  I want the legend to be a single row of elements such that I can easily put it at the bottom of my grid.  However, regardless of format on the original plot, g_legend always returns a legend with a single column.  Does anyone know of a way to force the legend to only have a single row?

```
#extract legend
#https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Share-a-legend-between-two-ggplot2-graphs
g_legend<-function(a.gplot){
  tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(a.gplot))
  leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
  legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]
  return(legend)}
```

Comment: Have you tried `nrow` parameter in `guide_legend`? See http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/guide_legend.html

Comment: Yeah, I tried setting nrow = 1 and still ended up with a legend of a single column with 3 rows.

Comment: I am able to change the legend format on the original ggplot figure, but when I pull it out using the g_legend function, it always reverts back to the default configuration.

Comment: no experience using this approach, sorry :(

Comment: do you have a reproducible example?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I found an error in my code that fixed the problem.  Using the nrow parameter in guide_legend does give a single row legend.  I just wasn't pulling the legend from the right plot.  Sorry, and thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and I've just solved it. You have to add legend options to your "p1.leg":

```
p1.leg <- ggplot(data,aes(v1, v2,colour=v3))+geom_area() + theme(legend.direction = "horizontal", legend.position = "bottom")
p1 <- ggplot(data, aes( v1, v2),
```

Then it works.